# Is calling an Async function from another function like this in sprinboot okay?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm calling my async function from another function like this.

```
AsyServiceImpl asyServiceImpl = new AsyServiceImpl();
asyServiceImpl.saveUsers(List);
```

The function in which I'm calling async function is in different service and different package in the springboot project.
The declaration of my async function looks like:

```
@Async
public void saveUsers(List<SomeModel> List) {
```

The problem is that I think my async function isn't being called because I'm not getting the result from it.

Comment: You're creating an object outside of the Spring Context, it can't apply the async capabilities unless spring creates the object.

Comment: Let String create the AsyServiceImpl by using @ Autowired AsyServiceImpl and make it a @ Component or @ Service